# How to get return error value if input wrong user name and password in SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have develop a program which interact with SVN client. 
From my program, I pass username and password to svn command line client to get log as below command:
   svn log --username 'myuser' --password 'mypassword' 'url of my repository'
When I input wrong username or password, SVN require input username and password again and again. But what I want that get return error to require my user inputs value again on my program's GUI.
I want to ask how to get return error value when I input wrong username or password.
And how to disable require username and password again if wrong in SVN.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try use option --non-interactive

> --non-interactive        : do no interactive prompting (default is to prompt
>                               only if standard input is a terminal device)

Comment: Thank to @Sergey Azarkevich. The great answer. And, I'm searching for getting return error value from SVN.